# An iOS app with embedded Citrix MDX toolkit crashes with "unable to obtain bundle for localization" error

Tags: ios, swift, citrix

I have an iOS app written in Swift 4.x running on iOS 11.x that crashes into an (not from me coded) alert that says three times `"Warning: Unable to obtain bundle for localization"` if it is deployed and started by Xcode to an actual device.

- I embedded the MDX / Worx frameworks
- I installed the Citrix Secure Hub App from the App Store

Prior the embedding the app ran smoothly without any problems. I was not able to find any resources from Citrix's support pages.

Does anybody have an idea or an "point of start to debug" for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late, but I had same problem and found solution.
In `MDXToolkit/data` folder there is `CitrixDylib.bundle` file. It needs to be attached to XCode project (simple drag&drop).

Then finally it's possible to see what's wrong:

Here is [screenshot before localization bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHfPP.png) with `"Warning: Unable to obtain bundle for localization"` message,

Here is [screenshot after localization bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZLHZ.png) with proper message: `App Not Available: The account for this app has been removed from Secure Hub. Please remove this app from your iPhone and reinstall it in Secure Hub.`

So if I understand correctly, app exits because is sideloaded, not installed through Secure Hub.

Comment: Thanks for the deep dive! I'm not able to test your fix, but it seems to make sense.